# Pivot rows to columns in SQL Server 2014

Tags: pivot, sql-server-2014

I have 3 tables like image in below link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0P-s1mtoHkaY2hJUEJuTnZOYTQ/view

Can I display result as above one?

I researched on Google and find out that it is gotten by using pivot in SQL. But I can not got it.
The helps will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right, you need a pivot query.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Please do not post images anywhere except at the Stack Overflow imgur (reachable by using the image toolbar button when writing your post). Using other locations for your content means it isn't certain to be available to future readers here, and since the vast majority of your content is contained in it, if it's not available then your post has no value and shouldn't be here. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try joining the user and role tables together via the junction table, and then pivoting to get each role as a separate column:

```
SELECT
    u.Id AS UserID,
    u.UserName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN r.Name = 'Admin'    THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS Admin,
    MAX(CASE WHEN r.Name = 'Manager'  THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS Manager,
    MAX(CASE WHEN r.Name = 'Employer' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS Employer
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN UserRole ur
    ON u.Id = ur.UserID
LEFT JOIN Role r
    ON ur.RoleID = r.Id
GROUP BY
    u.ID,
    u.UserName
ORDER BY
    u.Id
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for helping. It's useful to me.  But if it's so, when I add new role then it can not be displayed dynamic. Can you improve it?

Comment: @NvPeter If you are asking about how to add a new column for a new role in your dataset, if you want to do that automatically you would need dynamic SQL.